# Adding horizontal line at bottom of first two columns of a three-column table

Tags: multicol, supertabular

I have a table with a lot of data. I want it all on the same page and the only way to do that was to make it into three columns.  I was able to do that using the `multicol` package along with the `supertabular` package. I have one problem though. On the bottom of the first two columns there is no horizontal line (See first image). I tried the `\hline` command but it just put a horizontal line above the first line in the next column (see second image) and leaves the bottom of the first two columns the same.

I am open to any ideas even if it means making the table a completely different way. Thanks!

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[margin=1in,headheight=15pt]{geometry}

\newcount\n
\n=0
\def\tablebody{}
\makeatletter
\loop\ifnum\n<100
        \advance\n by1
        \protected@edef\tablebody{\tablebody
                \textbf{\number\n.}& shortText
                \tabularnewline
        }
\repeat

\makeatletter
\let\mcnewpage=\newpage
\newcommand{\TrickSupertabularIntoMulticols}{%
  \renewcommand\newpage{%
    \if@firstcolumn
      \hrule width\linewidth height0pt
      \columnbreak
    \else
      \mcnewpage
    \fi
  }%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\vgtwokspace}{V$_{\text{G2K}}$ }
\newcommand{\vgtwok}{V$_{\text{G2K}}$}

\begin{document}

\vspace*{8cm} %To place the start of the table at the same spot as my document

\begin{multicols*}{3}
\TrickSupertabularIntoMulticols
\tablehead{\hline\vgtwokspace & $\delta$\vgtwok & $I_{A}$& $\delta I_{A}$\\\hline}

\begin{supertabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\centering
    1     & 0.006 & 0     & 0.01 \\
    2     & 0.02  & 0     & 0.01 \\
    3     & 0.025 & 0     & 0.01 \\
    4     & 0.03  & 0     & 0.01 \\
    5     & 0.035 & 0     & 0.01 \\
    6     & 0.04  & 0     & 0.01 \\
    7     & 0.045 & 0     & 0.01 \\
    8     & 0.05  & 0     & 0.01 \\
    9     & 0.055 & 0     & 0.01 \\
    10    & 0.06  & 0     & 0.01 \\
    11    & 0.065 & 0     & 0.01 \\
    12    & 0.07  & 0     & 0.01 \\
    13.06 & 0.0753 & 0     & 0.01 \\
    14.04 & 0.0802 & 3     & 0.025 \\
    14.99 & 0.08495 & 9     & 0.055 \\
    15.92 & 0.0896 & 17    & 0.095 \\
    17.06 & 0.0953 & 27    & 0.235 \\
    17.95 & 0.09975 & 36    & 0.28 \\
    19.12 & 0.1056 & 47    & 0.335 \\
    20    & 0.2   & 55    & 0.375 \\
    21    & 0.205 & 62    & 0.41 \\
    22.1  & 0.2105 & 67    & 0.435 \\
    22.8  & 0.214 & 68    & 0.44 \\
    23.9  & 0.2195 & 66    & 0.43 \\
    25.1  & 0.2255 & 62    & 0.41 \\
    25.9  & 0.2295 & 60    & 0.4 \\
    27    & 0.235 & 64    & 0.42 \\
    28    & 0.24  & 77    & 0.485 \\
    29    & 0.245 & 95    & 0.575 \\
    30.1  & 0.2505 & 115   & 0.675 \\
    31    & 0.255 & 129   & 0.745 \\
    32    & 0.26  & 138   & 0.79 \\
    33    & 0.265 & 140   & 0.8 \\
    34    & 0.27  & 133   & 0.765 \\
    35.1  & 0.2755 & 117   & 0.685 \\
    35.9  & 0.2795 & 101   & 0.605 \\
    37.1  & 0.2855 & 77    & 0.485 \\
    38    & 0.29  & 70    & 0.45 \\
    39    & 0.295 & 85    & 0.525 \\
    40    & 0.3   & 120   & 0.7 \\
    41.1  & 0.3055 & 165   & 0.925 \\
    42    & 0.31  & 200   & 2 \\
    43    & 0.315 & 222   & 2.11 \\
    44    & 0.32  & 227   & 2.135 \\
    45    & 0.325 & 214   & 2.07 \\
    46.1  & 0.3305 & 179   & 0.995 \\
    47    & 0.335 & 139   & 0.795 \\
    48    & 0.34  & 99    & 0.595 \\
    49    & 0.345 & 72    & 0.46 \\
    50    & 0.35  & 80    & 0.5 \\
    51    & 0.355 & 129   & 0.745 \\
    52    & 0.36  & 203   & 2.015 \\
    53    & 0.365 & 280   & 2.4 \\
    54    & 0.37  & 333   & 2.665 \\
    55    & 0.375 & 355   & 2.775 \\
    56    & 0.38  & 354   & 2.77 \\
    57    & 0.385 & 322   & 2.61 \\
    58    & 0.39  & 258   & 2.29 \\
    59.1  & 0.3955 & 185   & 1.025 \\
    60    & 0.4   & 124   & 0.72 \\
    61    & 0.405 & 95    & 0.575 \\
    61.9  & 0.4095 & 132   & 0.76 \\
    62.9  & 0.4145 & 244   & 2.22 \\
    64    & 0.42  & 396   & 2.98 \\
    65    & 0.425 & 523   & 3.615 \\\hline
\end{supertabular}
\end{multicols*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Package `supertabular` beside  `\tablehead{...}` and `\tablefirsthead{...}`, which contain stuff to be repeated on each new page (or column) also define `\tabletail{...}` and `\tablelasttail{...}`.

In your case you just add`\tabletail{\hsline}` after `\tablehead` definition in your table.